# eventListener is not triggering

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
function expandTextarea () {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
        if (textareas[i].scrollHeight > 100) {
            textareas[i].style.height = textareas[i].scrollHeight + 2 + 'px';
        } else {
            textareas[i].style.height = '100px !important';
        }

        textareas[i].addEventListener('onchange', adjustTextareaHeight(this));
    // textareas[i].addEventListener('keyup', adjustTextareaHeight(textareas[i]));
    // textareas[i].addEventListener('paste', adjustTextareaHeight(textareas[i]));
    // textareas[i].addEventListener('cut', adjustTextareaHeight(textareas[i]));
    }
}

function adjustTextareaHeight (textarea) {
    console.log(textarea.length);
    if (textarea.length > 0) {
        textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 2 + 'px';
    }
}
```

For some reason the event listener is never fired. Note that `expandTextarea` is called from my `window.onload = function () {}` function.

When I call `expandTextarea` directly it runs without any issues but when I make a change, pressing enter a bunch, it never calls the `onchange` event.

Comment: There are probably a hundred dups of this question.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a **function** to `addEventListener`. Currently you are passing `undefined`, the *return value* of `adjustTextareaHeight`. So the browser doesn't know what to execute when the event occurs.

What you want is:

```
textareas[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
  adjustTextareaHeight(this);
});
```

---

In your code you are calling `adjustTextareaHeight` immediately (not on change). `this` likely refers to the global object (`window`) and `window.length` is `undefined`, which is not `> 0`.